# Stream URL to Android.Graphics.Bitmap using BitmapFactory.DecodeStreamAsync on GZIP file

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I need to decode a url to a Bitmap. I am using the following code to attempt to decode a stream.

```
async Task <Android.Graphics.Bitmap> GetImageFromUrl(string url) {
    using(var client = new HttpClient()) {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        if (response != null && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
            using(var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()) {
                return await BitmapFactory.DecodeStreamAsync(stream);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The url being supplied is a blank black image: https://assets.radiowave.io/prod/StationAssets/1/image-md.jpg

Why does the BitmapFactory.DecodeStreamAsync always return null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass a GZIP'd stream to `DecodeStream` and thus it fails to determine the type image you are passing in. Add a `HttpClientHandler` to your `HttpClient` with automatic decompression enabled.

FYI: If this method is being called multiple times, you should treat `HttpClient` as a singleton and only createi t once.

```
async Task<Android.Graphics.Bitmap> GetBitmapFromUrlAsync(string url)
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip
    };
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        if (response != null && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                return await BitmapFactory.DecodeStreamAsync(stream);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer to use the available Java API's since there are tons of examples that do work so the code should look something like this:

```
 public async Task<Bitmap> GetBitmapFromUrlAsync(String src)
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.OpenConnection();
            connection.DoInput = (true);
            await connection.ConnectAsync();
            Stream input = connection.InputStream;
            Bitmap myBitmap = await BitmapFactory.DecodeStreamAsync(input);
            return myBitmap;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // Log exception
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And you will need the following using statements:

```
using Java.Net;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.Graphics;
```

Also since you are making an API call make sure you have the try-catch ready.